# Create a pie chart that will count multiple columns sql vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, pie-chart

So I'm creating a pie chart that will count the number of items in a column, the problem is it also counts the null items, i can make the query not count the nulls only on one column, it displays nothing when i make it not count the null on more than 1 column. And when a row has a value on multiple columns for example row 1 has a value on violation1 and violation2, there will be a portion in the pie chart that counts both of them as a new value.

here is my code -

```
    Dim cnn3 As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd3 As New SqlCommand
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
    Try
        cnn3.ConnectionString = Login.sqlcode
        cmd3.Connection = cnn3
        Dim tblFields As String = "SELECT count(*) as [Vio] from Violations WHERE Violation1<> '" & "NULL" & "' Group by Violation1, Violation2, Violation3, Violation4, Violation5, Violation6, Violation7, Violation8"
        Dim oData As New SqlDataAdapter(tblFields, cnn3)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim oCmd As New SqlCommand(tblFields, cnn3)
        cnn3.Open()
        oData.Fill(ds, "Violations")
        cnn3.Close()
        Chart1.DataSource = ds.Tables("Violations")
        Dim Series1 As Series = Chart1.Series("Series1")
        Series1.Name = "Violations"
        Chart1.Series(Series1.Name).YValueMembers = "Vio"
        Chart1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(780, 350)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error while connecting to SQL Server." & ex.Message)
    End Try
```

I think the problem is in the query, what im trying to achieve here is for the pie chart to display the counts of column violation1-8, without nulls and without combining the values.

Comment: Are you wanting a single value, or each particular columns count? A simple `SELECT Count(Violation1), Count(Violation2) ... Count(Violation7) FROM Violations` Should ignore any null values in each column.

Comment: @CharlesMay thank you for the response, but how do I show this in a pie chart, because my query has "as [Vio]" and that what i call in chart series to create a chart, but with your query, i dont know how to do it.

Comment: You would need to change this according to what you want to show. I assume you want a pie representation of the total of Violation1, Violation2, etc... `Why not SELECT Count(Violation1) AS Violation1...`? This would then show what each "slice" of the pie represented on your legend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick workup of what I'm describing.

Assume the table holds the following information:
[image]

By running the query:

```
SELECT Count(Violation1) AS Violation1,
       Count(Violation2) AS Violation2,
       Count(Violation3) AS Violation3,
       Count(Violation4) AS Violation4,
       Count(Violation5) AS Violation5
FROM Violations
```

We end up with the following results:

[image]

These results when put into a dataset makes it quite easy to display a graph.

Here we populate a graph using our Dataset we filled from our query result.

```
    Chart1.Series.Clear()
    Chart1.Series.Add("Series1")
    'we only have one row so we only need to loop through the columns
    'of our row (Rows(0))  
    For Each c As DataColumn In ds.Tables(0).Columns
        Chart1.Series(0).Points.AddXY(c.ColumnName, ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(c.ColumnName).ToString)
    Next
    Chart1.Series(0).ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Pie
    Chart1.Series(0).IsValueShownAsLabel = True 'show the value of each "slice"
```

Leaving us with the following graph:

[image]